# Run curl with another user in CMD

Tags: cmd.exe, curl

Here's my question: When i start CMD locally as a current user and run following command:

```
curl "https://desktop.docker.com/win/main/amd64/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe?utm_source=docker&utm_medium=webreferral&utm_campaign=docs-driven-download-win-amd64" --output "C:\Docker-Temp\docker_install.exe"
```

everything works as it should, the file is being downloaded

[image: (see screenshot here)]

If i try to do the same over our deployment software with a domain admin account, it looks like it downloads a shortcut to a file with the size of 1 KB
[image: (see screenshot here)]

What do i do wrong or how to this the right way?

Comment: can you try this command instead? `cd C:\Docker-Temp\ && C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command iwr "https://desktop.docker.com/win/main/amd64/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe?utm_source=docker&utm_medium=webreferral&utm_campaign=docs-driven-download-win-amd64" -outfile "docker_installer.exe"`

Comment: I get the following error message

Comment: In Zeile:1 Zeichen:98
+ ... in/main/amd64/Docker0Desktop0Installer.exe?utm_source=docker&utm_medi ...
+                                                                 ~
Das kaufmännische Und-Zeichen (&) ist nicht zulässig. Der &-Operator ist für eine zukünftige Verwendung reserviert.
Verwenden Sie das kaufmännische Und-Zeichen in doppelten Anführungszeichen ("&"), um es als Teil einer Zeichenfolge zu
übergeben.

Comment: In Zeile:1 Zeichen:121
+ ... sktop0Installer.exe?utm_source=docker&utm_medium=webreferral&utm_camp ...
+                                                                 ~
Das kaufmännische Und-Zeichen (&) ist nicht zulässig. Der &-Operator ist für eine zukünftige Verwendung reserviert.
Verwenden Sie das kaufmännische Und-Zeichen in doppelten Anführungszeichen ("&"), um es als Teil einer Zeichenfolge zu
übergeben.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed

Comment: Sorry that it is in German, i hope you understand the meaning anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was that the URL was including question marks with useless information on them(desktop.docker.com/win/main/amd64/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe **?utm_source=docker&utm_medium=webreferral&utm_campaign=docs-driven-download-win-amd64**).

I removed the question marks and here's the quick script that should work *(tested)*:

**docker.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Changing the directory to C:\Docker-Temp\...
cd C:\Docker-Temp\
echo Installing Docker Desktop Installer...
echo iwr "https://desktop.docker.com/win/main/amd64/Docker Desktop Installer.exe" -outfile "docker_installer.exe" > docker.ps1
timeout 1
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File docker.ps1
echo Success! Enjoy
```

Enjoy, have fun!